# adding random value to array and comparing first two value js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn some simple things in js, so what i am trying to achieve is every time I get a random number I want to add it inside an array at he front, then compare the first two values make sure they are not  `[6,6]`

```
function randomNumber() {
  number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  return number;
}

function addValue() {
  var score = [];
  score.unshift(randomNumber());
  console.log(score);
  return score;
}
```

At the moment what is happening, every time i call the randomNumber the array only stores one value, it does not append it to the list and overweights the previous.

What am I doing wrong and why is it working? thx

Comment: Why do you care about the first 2 numbers matching, anyways?

Answer (score 2):

the variable you use to store the array needs to be created and passed through the argument list, or stored globally.
when you do `var x = []` you are create a NEW empty array.

```js
  var score = [];
  
  addValue(score);
  addValue(score);
  addValue(score);

function randomNumber() {
  number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  return number;
}

function addValue(score) {

  score.unshift(randomNumber());
}

console.log(score)
```